# Why fluid pressure on the bottom in an inverted T container is uniform?

Tags: fluid-statics

The problem for me is this line of reasoning:

> The pressure at a point in a static liquid is due entirely to the weight of liquid (plus the atmosphere) directly above it.

This and similar wording are everywhere in introduction papers.
But at the "corners" of an inverted T container there is hardly anything "directly above" it! But still I see no mentioning of this "problem". I certaintly think pressure at corners should be equal to pressure right under the stem of T otherwise water will flow (and we are talking about static fluids here).

But why there is always this "directly above" phrase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not forget the role of the container which exerts forces on the water and you have a static situation so the net force on every point in the water is zero.

The downward force (green) on point $A$ due to the column of water above it ($h$) and the atmosphere is balance by the upward force due to the water (blue) below that point.

[image]

I have moved point $B$ away from the corner just for convenience.
At point $B$ there is an upward force (blue) on it due to water below it which is the same size as the upward force exerted on point $A$ but this time the downward force on point $B$ is due to the wall of the container. 
This force is exactly the same as that exerted by the column of water $h$ and the atmosphere.

The "directly above" is there because it is the vertical height of the column of water which is important.

Comment: hmm. You say that the wall over B exerts pressure equal to "atmos pressure + weight  of the water column to the LEFT of point B". Why wall will do that? :) Sorry for the stupid question. I'm not joking. I just can't get it.

Comment: If the wall was not there the water would come out.  If the forces up and down were not equal there would not be a static equilibrium situation.